# ruby on rails map not showing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I have updated my gemfile to include geocoder and gmaps4rails and followed the version 2 tutorial, it loads the page but without the map. I don't know why this is happening.

application.js

```
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps/google
//= require_tree .
```

character_controller file

```
class CharactersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_character, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /characters
  # GET /characters.json
  def index
    @characters = Character.all
    #json = Character.all.to_gmaps4rails
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@characters) do |character, marker|
  marker.lat character.latitude
  marker.lng character.longitude
end
  end
```

I have also done the bundle update and bundle install, restarted the server numerous times. Am I missing something?

Please advise @apneadiving

Comment: How are you calling your map in the view?

Comment: <%= link_to 'New Character', new_character_path %>


<div style='width: 800px;'>
  <div id="map" style='width: 800px; height: 400px;'></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
  markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
  handler.fitMapToBounds();
});

Comment: do you create your underscore.js file? you should download that from [underscore site](http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js), i cheked all your code and works ok on my server

Comment: hey i got that working ... thanks a lot.... i was missing a end script tag.... shitty stuff

Comment: delete your questions if they have no more interest